# WSO2 ESB - Customise Browser for ESB Identity

Tags: wso2-esb

Is there any way to customize the user browser experience.

I have multiple ESB's and its easy to accidentally configure one thinking you are in another. The port seem to be the only differentiator.

I was thinking along the lines of being able to set a banner text -

e.g. "I'm In UAT"  etc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the WSO2 Documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Customizing+the+Management+Console), You can customize the Management console as per your need.

Customizing the product interface involves changing the layout/design of the Carbon framework as well as changing the styles and images specific to the product.

Specifically, you can do the following.

- Changing the layout
- Changing the styles on the Carbon framework
- Changing the product specific styles and images

Comment: Thanks, I missed that feature & it works, my only observation is its a bit heavy weight solution. A nice to have would be to have some local registry text written over the header. Thanks anyway - good answer.